# How do I filter a datetime field using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've written the following SQLAlchemy query:

```
db.get_session().query(Order, Order.created, Order.symbol).filter(Order.symbol=='GE').all()
```

Which produces an output like this:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is is get the ones where `Order.created == '2017-02-03'`.

I've tried `db.get_session().query(Order, Order.created, Order.symbol).filter(Order.symbol=='GE').filter(Order.created=='2017-02-03').all()` but it doesn't work (no result).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's because the order date include the time, so you need to use `range compare` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using func.date()

```
from sqlalchemy import func
db.get_session().query(Order, Order.created, Order.symbol).filter(func.date(Order.created) == '2017-02-03').all()
```